# Помощь по сайту (bitrix)

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу сделать ? Мне нужно, чтобы получилось как на второй картинке. Чтобы товары были расположены не по одному в строку, а по 2 или 3. Подскажите пожалуйста, как этого добиться... Или хотя бы в каких местах искать свойства, что изменить можно...... Заранее спасибо..[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо зайти в настройки каталога и там в отделе общего вида надо вставить  сколько элементов будет на одной строке.

 PS   обратите внимание чтобы при сохранении был выбран ваш шаблон.

 PSS попробуйте прочитать [ТУТ](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/product_features/using-and-customizing-the-catalog-component-version-14.php)

Comment: Спасибо, но вот еще один вопрос.  Почему у меня элементы загружаются не по очереди? В том плане, что после первого товара делается пропуск. Может знаете?  http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1702/80/776218242134.png

Comment: "делается пропуск" - что это значит? показывает другой продукт? например  1,3,4,2  ?

Comment: не совсем. Как на скрине я показал. Т.е Если я делаю по 3 элемента в строку, то он на первой строке показывает товар1,товар2, потом пропуск большой, и потом уже с новой строки продолжает. Если делаю по 2 в строку, то он показывает товар1, потом пропуск большой, потом с новой строки все оставшиеся товары.

Comment: насколько помню, там в настройках тоже должно быть место для вставки количества Leading product, т.е вступительный продукт, могу ошибатся, так же проверьте в дебагере , какая структура в html ? возможно по дефолту там в стилях прописанно что первый продукт одолжен быть один на строке

Comment: вообще не понимаю, как найти такие настройки ((